# Highlight custom days in DatePicker

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, .net-maui

I was wondering how to override custom Android DatePicker template with my own. Basically I need to somehow highlight certain dates in DatePicker. I have seen a lot of similar questions in the Internet, but not that many solutions. Maybe as time has passed there are some ways of achieving this already?

I am looking for some way to overriding existing DatePicker without creating full copy of standard one. In WPF for example you can extract styles and make some custom modifications to standard templates. Is there some similar way in Xamarin? Or is it really so that I have to redo everything existing from scratch myself?

As an output I would like to have something like this (red dots under specific dates):

[image]

Comment: Well to my knowledge, iOS and Android have their own templates for DatePickers and if you want to customize this, you will have to create your own control from scratch, There are very specific changes that you can do in DatePickers.  Checkout https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker

Comment: Just overriding wont do the trick, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You can highlight date by using `XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate`.
create a special date list(highlight) with `XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate` and set property value (*like BackgroundColor,TextColor*) for style your special days.

```
  public ObservableCollection<XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate> specialDates { get; set; }
```

```cs
        foreach (Birthday b in birthdays)
        {
            specialDates.Add(new XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate(b.Date) { BackgroundColor = Color.Green, TextColor = Color.White, BorderColor = Color.Yellow, BorderWidth = 8, Selectable = true });
        }
```

```cs
 <StackLayout>
        <controls:Calendar
            Padding="10,0,10,0"
            BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=Black,
                                              Light=White}"
            DateCommand="{Binding DateChosen}"
            DatesBackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=Black,
                                                   Light=White}"
            DatesTextColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=White,
                                             Light=Black}"
            DisabledBorderColor="Black"
            SelectedBorderWidth="4"
            SelectedDate="{Binding Date}"
            ShowNumberOfWeek="false"
            SpecialDates="{Binding attendances}"
            StartDay="Sunday"
            TitleLabelTextColor="Purple"
            TitleLeftArrowTextColor="MediumVioletRed"
            TitleRightArrowTextColor="MediumVioletRed" />

        <ListView
            x:Name="birthdayListView"
            BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Dark=Black,
                                              Light=#444343}"
            HeightRequest="250"
            ItemsSource="{Binding birthdays}"
            WidthRequest="50">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextCell
                        Detail="{Binding Date}"
                        DetailColor="YellowGreen"
                        Text="{Binding FullName}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>

public partial class Page38 : ContentPage, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Birthday> _birthdays;
    public List<Birthday> birthdays 
    {
        get { return _birthdays; }
        set
        {
            _birthdays = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("birthdays");
        }
    }
    private DateTime? _date;
    public DateTime? Date
    {
        get
        {
            return _date;
        }
        set
        {
            _date = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Date));
        }
    }
    public ObservableCollection<XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate> attendances { get; set; }
    public ICommand DateChosen
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command((obj) => {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(obj as DateTime?);
            });
        }
    }

    public Page38()
    {
        InitializeComponent();      
        attendances = new ObservableCollection<SpecialDate>();
        Date = DateTime.Now;
        this.BindingContext = this;
    
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        //get data from sqlite database.
         birthdays = new List<Birthday>()
        {
            new Birthday(){FirstName="cherry", Date=new DateTime(2021,5,25), },
            new Birthday(){FirstName="cherry", Date=new DateTime(2021,5,26), },
            new Birthday(){FirstName="cherry", Date=new DateTime(2021,5,27), },
            new Birthday(){FirstName="cherry", Date=new DateTime(2021,5,28), },
            new Birthday(){FirstName="cherry", Date=new DateTime(2021,5,30), },
            new Birthday(){FirstName="cherry", Date=new DateTime(2021,5,31), },

        };
        //add Date property to  attendances
        foreach (Birthday b in birthdays)
        {
            attendances.Add(new XamForms.Controls.SpecialDate(b.Date) { BackgroundColor = Color.Green, TextColor = Color.White, BorderColor = Color.Yellow, BorderWidth = 8, Selectable = true });
        }

    }
    
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:**
you can use simple [nuget package](https://github.com/lubiepomaranczki/XamForms.Controls.Calendar) to highlight date in calender.
[image]
Ref:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67771417/highlighting-days-in-a-xamforms-calendar)
[link2](https://github.com/rebeccaXam/XamForms.Controls.Calendar)
[link3](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ff00d495-89d6-4cd2-a65e-0a87124ec00d/xamarin-forms-issue-with-special-date-selection-in-xamformscontrolscalendar?forum=xamarinforms)
[ISO Issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/195483/xamarin-forms-specialdate-feature-is-not-working-i.html)